# Port Address already in use: bind

Tags: jenkins

Facing issues with Jenkins
With every restart I need to start Jenkins with some unique Port.
With every new launch I have to use cmd like:java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081(new port everytime)
Note:I tried killing pid ports used earlier like 8080,8090,8081.
Please suggest how to resolve this on Windows.

Please help,how can we use the same ports again?

Comment: there might be windows service of jenkins/any other running on that host. stop that service and then use the port 8080.

Comment: Although it's not a good practice, you can still try running the Jenkins through some server like tomcat. just place the jenkins.war in webapps of tomcat and start the server.

Comment: Can it be jenkins version issue? as I am facing issues with email notification as well.Jenkins version-Jenkins ver. 2.193